# Efficiently replace unwanted separator from csv field

Tags: c#, csv

As input, I have a csv file of approximately 1,000,000 lines (about 300Mb) which contains columns separated by semi-colons.

```
colA;colB;colC;colD;colE
aaaa;bbbb;cccc;dddd;"eeee;"
aaaa;bbbb;cccc;dddd;evfvdfeee
aaaa;bb1bb;cc2cc;dd3dd;evfve
```

Some of the fields on the 5th column may have a semi-colon. Not all of them though. So, I want to remove all semi-colons after the 4th occurrence. The code below works, but it takes ages (approx. 10min) to save the csv to the file. How can I speed up this?

```
void Main()
{

    string finput = @"myfile.csv";
    FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(finput);

    var Lines = File.ReadLines(finfo.FullName);
    List<string> output = new List<string>();
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    int count = 0;

        foreach (string s in Lines)
        {
            count++;
            if (count % 10000 == 0)
                count.Dump();

          output.Add((StringExtender.ReplaceAfterNthOccurrency(s, ";", ".", 5)));
    }
    sw.Elapsed.Dump();

    File.WriteAllLines(finfo.DirectoryName + finfo.Name + "_conv.csv", output);
}

public static class StringExtender
{
    public static string ReplaceAfterNthOccurrency(string input, string to_replace, string to_add, int n)
    {

        var cont = true;
        int count = 0;
        int start = 0;
        while (cont)
        {
            int i = input.IndexOf(to_replace, start);

            if (i != -1)
            {
                count++;
                start = i + 1;
                if (count >= n)
                {
                    input = input.Remove(i, 1);
                    input = input.Insert(i, to_add);
                }
            }
            else
                cont = false;

        }
        return input;

    }
}
```

Comment: Use StringBuilder

Comment: thanks @JonBrave . I fixed the text

Comment: @JonBrave ooops. Sorry, I missed it. It's fixed now

Comment: Speed up by which amount? 1%, 10x, 10000x? How large is the input file?

Comment: You could definitely multithread this. Create as many new StringBuilder instances as threads and then combine them in the end.

Comment: @ThomasWeller  approximately 1,000,000 lines (about 300Mb)

Comment: i'm not sure its the replacing process that takes 10 minutes long, did you try simply loading the file, then saving it as it is, is it any faster ?

Comment: Apart from the replacement code, you're reading all 1,000,000 lines into memory, and constructing another 1,000,000 in memory before outputting.  Footprint > 600MB.  Doing a line at a time input then output may or may not save time, but it should save a lot of unnecessary memory!

Comment: Is your actual goal simply to parse the CSV file *correctly*, i.e. to ignore separators if they occur between quotes?

Comment: @Stavm I'm testing the saving time right now.

Comment: @Groo yes, I need to "polish" the csv in order to process it with another piece of software.

Comment: So, the majority of the time is taken by the saving process. Making a copy of the file reading line by line took also 10 minutes.

Comment: Using StreamWriter took 11 min :-( I think I'm hitting the bottleneck.

Comment: 11 minutes for reading and writing 300 MB? What hardware is this? [HugeJsonViewer](https://development.wellisolutions.de/huge-json-viewer/) reads 1.4 GB in 1:16 minutes on my machine

Comment: Yeah.  Maybe the file is on a network, or on a USB stick...!  What is the base time to simply copy your file from its actual source to its actual destination via a command-line "copy" or even File Explorer?  From there one can see if your code's time seems at all reasonable before analysing it further.